# Conditional Formatting for round birthdays as a reminder

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have an issue in my formula.
Intention: If a person has a round birthday (from 70 onwards: 70, 75, 80, 85, ...) the age should be highlighted in red 30 days before the birthday.

the formula works quite well, but it seems to have issues if the birthday is within a range of 30 days going into the next year.

I cannot figure out how to modify the formula so it works how it should. Any help appreciated!

**formula:**

> =AND(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(J3),DAY(J3))>=TODAY(),DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(J3),DAY(J3))<=TODAY()+30,MOD((INT((TODAY()-J3)/365)+1),5)=0,(INT((TODAY()-J3)/365))+1>69)

example in the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=AND(AND(
            YEAR(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()) + (DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH($J3),DAY($J3))<TODAY()), MONTH($J3),DAY($J3)))-YEAR($J3)>=70,
            MOD(YEAR(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()) + (DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH($J3),DAY($J3))<TODAY()),MONTH($J3),DAY($J3)))-YEAR($J3),5)=0),
        DATE(YEAR(TODAY()) + (DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH($J3),DAY($J3))<TODAY()),MONTH($J3),DAY($J3))-TODAY()<=30)
```

[image]

- Compute **next** birthday (note we add a year if the computed birthday is before `TODAY()`); Also note that **leapling birthdays** will be on `1 Mar` of a non leap year.

  `=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()) +  DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH($J3),DAY($J3))<TODAY()),MONTH($J3),DAY($J3))`
- Age at next birthday (just have to subtract years
- Then it's just a matter of checking if it is a rounded age 70+ and within 30 days of today.